# where query from table with column foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have table listings and cities,  listings hasOne cities relationship.
there are 2 inputs, first input is to look name of listing and second input is to look name of city.
Listings table has column name and city_id.
Cities table has column id and name.

The goal is to look for listing in city input.

the current query look like this

```
$listings = Listing::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search. '%')->where('%'. $request->location. '%', 'LIKE', function($query){
            $query->where(DB::raw('cities.name'));
        })->paginate(10);
```

this give error column unknow

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '%city input%' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `listings` where `name` LIKE %listing input% and `%city input%` LIKE (select * where cities.name is null))

any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) is what you need.

Assuming your relationship is called "city":

```
$listings = Listing::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
    ->whereHas('city', function($query) use($request) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->location . '%');
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```